# Printing the max of groups of three random ints

Tags: java, beginner, stream, lambda

I'm trying to teach myself streaming and lambda expressions. Here's the scenario: I have a collection of 10 Thing objects each containing an int[] of 3 random number. I've written code to print out the largest number in each Thing.

I've already written two statements and an accompanying method that print the result I want, however the code is pretty ropey... improvements and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Thing {
    private Random r = new Random();
    private int a = r.nextInt(), b = r.nextInt(), c = r.nextInt();

    public int[] getCollectionOfInts() {
        return collectionOfInts;
    }

    private int[] collectionOfInts = new int[]{a, b, c};

}//end of class

//main in separate driver class
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing[] things = new Thing[10];
        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        for (int x =0;x<10;x++){
            things[x] = new Thing();
            for (int y=0;y<things[x].getCollectionOfInts().length;y++)
            {
                if(y==0)
                    a = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
                if(y==1)
                    b = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
                if(y==2)
                    c = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
            }
            //print 3 numbers in each Thing object
            System.out.println(x+": "+a+", "+b+", "+c);
        }
        System.out.println();

        //compare each number and print out largest... too many ternaries 
        Stream.of(things).forEach(Thing->System.out.println(Stream.of(Thing.getCollectionOfInts()).mapToInt(z->z[0]>z[1]&&z[0]>z[2]?z[0]:z[1]>z[2]?z[1]:z[2]).reduce((x,y)->x+y).getAsInt()));
        System.out.println();
        //improper use of .max() or .mapToInt(...)?
        Stream.of(things).forEach(Thing->System.out.println(Stream.of(Thing.getCollectionOfInts()).mapToInt(x->maxInt(x)).max().getAsInt()));

    }
    public static int maxInt(int[] x) {
        int max=x[0];
        for (int y:x) {
            if(y>max)
                max = y;
        }
        return max;
    }
```

I get the expected results for both streams, but I'm still unhappy with how I get there!

Answer (score 3):

The first thing about your code are the two lines inside your class `Thing`:

```
private Random r = new Random();
private int a = r.nextInt(), b = r.nextInt(), c = r.nextInt();
```

If Random r is used just to initialize the array and not in other methods inside the class , it is better to use it in the costructor of the class :

```
public Thing() {
    Random r = new Random();
    this.arr = new int[] {r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt()};
}
```

You can check I initialize directy here the array of ints instead of defining variables a, b, c.
A good thing is also override the String method to print the internal state of a object:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(arr);
}
```

Now you can print the state of your `Thing` object in this way:

```
for (int i = 0;i < 10; ++i){
    things[i] = new Thing();
    //print 3 numbers in each Thing object
    System.out.println(i + ": " + things[i]);
}
```

Your iterations with `Stream` are ok, but instead of use `Stream` because you are working with `int` values you can use instead [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) simplifyng the code:

```
Stream.of(things).forEach(t -> System.out.println(Arrays.stream(t.getArr()).max().getAsInt()));
```

Below the code of class `Thing` including all my modifies:

```
package codereview;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Thing {

    private int[] arr;

    public Thing() {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.arr = new int[] {r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt()};
    }

    public int[] getArr() {
        return arr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(arr);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing[] things = new Thing[10];
        for (int i = 0;i <10; ++i){
            things[i] = new Thing();
            //print 3 numbers in each Thing object
            System.out.println(i + ": " + things[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        Stream.of(things).forEach(t -> System.out.println(Arrays.stream(t.getArr()).max().getAsInt()));
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your code could benefit from being formatted consistently by an IDE. Apart from that, it's nice and simple. I also refactored the OP's code and reached very similar code.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks, I'm still messing when I copy code from IDE here.

Comment: There's a simple recipe against messed up code: just forget about the 4 spaces of indentation and surround the code by `~~~`. That's much easier to get right.

Comment: @RolandIllig I didn't know this,  I apply it in the next answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Advice  1: code packaging**

I suggest you put your `Thing` related code into a package. That way you may practice industrial level programming:

```
package net.tnm;
```

Note that the above package name is just an example. Usually, is should be reversed domain name of your company. (For example, `package com.oracle.xxx` where `xxx` is the project name.)

**Advice 2: code layout**
You have this:

```
private int a = r.nextInt(), b = r.nextInt(), c = r.nextInt();
```

I would suggest

```
private final int a = r.nextInt(), 
                  b = r.nextInt(), 
                  c = r.nextInt();
```

**Advice 3: declaring immutable fields final**

Once again:

```
private final int a = r.nextInt(), 
                  b = r.nextInt(), 
                  c = r.nextInt();
```

**Advice 4: spaces around binary operators**

A *binary operator* is an operator that that takes **two** operands. You often write, for example, `y=0`, when the coding conventions dictate `y = 0`.

**Advice 5: bracing**

You have 
        `for (int x =0;x<10;x++){`

when you should write

```
    for (int x =0;x<10;x++) {
                           ^
                         space
```

Also,

```
for (int y=0;y<things[x].getCollectionOfInts().length;y++)
{
```

is C/C++ style. In Java, it is customary to write

```
for (int y=0;y<things[x].getCollectionOfInts().length;y++) {
```

**Advice 6: lambdas**

```
Stream.of(things).forEach(Thing->System...
```

Since `Thing` is a variable in that context and not a type, I would rename it to `thing`.

**Advice 7: max of three**

You have this:

```
z -> z[0] > z[1] && z[0] > z[2] ? z[0] : z[1] > z[2] ? z[1] : z[2]
```

A shorter way of writing the same is

```
z -> Math.max(z[0], Math.max(z[1], z[2]))
```

**Advice 8: maxInt**

You can write it as

```
public static int maxInt(int[] x) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i : x) {
        max = Math.max(max, i);
    }

    return max;
}
```

**Advice 9: redundant `if` statements**

```
if(y==0)
    a = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
if(y==1)
    b = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
if(y==2)
    c = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
```

Only one of those `if` statements will be executed yet all the condition will be checked. Basically, you can do this:

```
if (y == 0) { 
    a = ...
} else if (y == 1) {
    b = ...
} else {
    c = ...
}
```

**Advice 10: naked `if` statements**

Once again, you have

```
if (y==0)
    a = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[y];
```

More idiomatic Java is this:

```
if (y == 0) {
    a = ...
}
```

(Note the braces.)

**Summa summarum**

I had this in mind:

**Thing.java**

```
package net.tnm;

import java.util.Random;

public class Thing {

    private final Random r = new Random();
    private final int a = r.nextInt(), 
                      b = r.nextInt(), 
                      c = r.nextInt();

    private int[] collectionOfInts = new int[]{a, b, c};

    public int[] getCollectionOfInts() {
        return collectionOfInts;
    }
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
package net.tnm;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing[] things = new Thing[10];
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            things[x] = new Thing();

            for (int y = 0; y < things[x].getCollectionOfInts().length; y++) {
                switch (y) {
                    case 0:
                        a = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[0];
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        b = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[1];
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        c = things[x].getCollectionOfInts()[2];
                        break;
                }
            }

            //print 3 numbers in each Thing object
            System.out.println(x + ": " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
        }

        System.out.println();

        Stream.of(things)
              .forEach(thing -> System.out.println(
                        Stream.of(thing.getCollectionOfInts())
                            .mapToInt(z -> Math.max(z[0], Math.max(z[1], z[2])))
                            .reduce((x, y) -> x + y)
                            .getAsInt()
                       )
              );

        System.out.println();

        Stream.of(things)
              .forEach(thing -> System.out.println(
                      Stream.of(thing.getCollectionOfInts())
                            .mapToInt(x -> maxInt(x))
                            .max()
                            .getAsInt()));

    }

    public static int maxInt(int[] x) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i : x) {
            max = Math.max(max, i);
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is missing explanations for many of your suggestions. Remember that the OP is a beginner. +++ Why would `net.tnm` be an appropriate package name? +++ In idiomatic Java code, there's no reason to write your own `max` helper function. +++ The `switch` is completely useless and can be replaced by 3 simple variable assignments, it's a pattern that often appears in beginner code.